# Uploader component design

Tags: design, users, experience, component, upload

Good morning guys.

This is my first post, so hi everyone =) .
I need some help with the design of a uploader angular component, what I'm trying to achieve is create two components in one, a single uploader and a multiple uploader.

For the first one, the single, I was trying to display only one button and over the button the progress information.(This one will be used also to upload your own avatar or single documents in forms)

[image: single upload]

In this case I want to leave the user the option to download/remove the uploaded file, so my first question is... how is done in the rest of uploader components? icons, contextual menu, links...
[image: Multiple 1] [image: Multiple 2]

For the multiple I want to display the list of files with the progress and I created something like that. First you load the list of files and then you can upload the files to the server.

Then the question I have some doubts about the different between the single and the multiple component, one is using the label of the button to display info and the other progress bars.. I don't know... Do you think it should be represented in the same way?

And my last question is about drag and drop, how I should implement it in terms of design in the multiple uploader?
Should I create a dotted box around the entire component to be able to drag and drop documents over the component(over the progress bar, buttons..) or maybe I should create a different area around the component for the drag and drop??

In short, because yeah, my english is really poor, I want to ask you:

1 - Best way to be able to **display progress** and inform the user about the upload situation in a **single upload**.

2 - Best way to be able to **remove/download** the previous file in a **single upload**.

3 - Should **both components** display data in the same way for a **better ux**?
Like if you're using progress bar and icons... use it also for the single mode.

4 - If I want to add a drag and drop, should I choose between the list or the drag and drop, combine both or create different areas for the list a for the drag and drop??

I'm completely open to new ideas, I don't have any requirement and for me is really important the user experience and I understand is not something simple that everybody can decide with no documentation/experience.

Sorry guys for my english and to use my first post to ask instead resolve any question...

Kto

Comment: You're asking a lot of questions in one post here. Can you refocus it down to a single question that can be answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your questions quickly, I'm gonna pull up screenshots from a project I worked on where I had to design similar components. I hope they are of help to you.

**1 - Best way to be able to display progress and inform the user about the upload situation in a single upload.**

[[image: A basic file uploader progress by [1]]

Additionally, you could show the percentage of file uploaded (this depends on the sizes of what they are uploading):

[image: https://usersnap.com/blog/progress-indicators/]

**2 - Best way to be able to remove/download the previous file in a single upload.**

What you have up there with a delete icon works. You could try using a Call to Action though, like "Remove file" or "Delete file"

[image]

**3 - Should both components display data in the same way for a better ux? Like if you're using progress bar and icons... use it also for the single mode.**

Yes. Consistency is one the heuristics of good user experience design.

**4 - If I want to add a drag and drop, should I choose between the list or the drag and drop, combine both or create different areas for the list a for the drag and drop??**

I will say combine both.
Generally, most users will already be used to what we call a "drop zone": (the dotted line), it's a very popular ux pattern.

[image]

You should also make it known that it is possible to select multiple files e.g using a call to action like "Add your file(s)". This should also be made possible with your code:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your time, I will try to follow your advise to keep the consistency =)